# Do NodaTime constructors accept 24 in the Hours parameter

Tags: iso, nodatime

I am hoping to get a quick answer to one question about NodaTime before downloading it. So far, I am reading about NodaTime and its API and it seems very carefully thought out.

I hope it might help eliminate some of the chaos I've been encountering in an application that has a database back-end, a desktop client with a database provider, and a web client that must run on the major browsers. The support for ISO 8601 on DateTime and Time varies greatly on the various database, database provider, and web platforms. Internet Explorer, for example, follows ISO 8601 but SQL Server does not; web UI timepickers do not because Chrome does not.

**QUESTION: In NodaTime, is 24:00 a valid Time value? Is 24 a valid argument for the hours parameter of its Time constructors?**

BACKGROUND: ISO 8601 allows for two representations of midnight: 00:00 for "midnight this morning" and 24:00 for "midnight tonight". When the DateTime object is *on* the time-line, a date whose time element has 24:00 coincides with the next day at 00:00. They are the same time-line instant with two different representations, both representations valid per ISO.

A Time-only value is detached from the time-line. A time of 00:00 occurs at the beginning of the detached 24-hour day and a Time-only value of 24:00 is 24 hours after 00:00.  A Time type should accept 24 in the hour. When 24 is the hour the maximum value for seconds and milliseconds and ticks is 0 (unless modulo arithmetic is involved and the time rolls over, so that 24:01 is 00:01 -- but ISO has nothing to say about this implementation detail, IIRC).

Comment: Aside from my answer, it's not clear what you mean by "ISO 5.3.2". This is described in section 4.2.3 of ISO-8601. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry about that. Added ISO 8601. Thanks for the detailed info. I'll add the request. I may have an older revision. It was the section on DateTime and Time I was reading.

Comment: Here in the ISO ECMAscript standards, which are a "simplification of IS8061 Extended Format", the discussion occurs in section 15.9.1.15 on page 169: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We accept 24:00 when parsing a `LocalDateTime`, but *not* 24:01.

This was [issue 153](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=153), implemented in [revision f7ac0365d8ca](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/detail?r=f7ac0365d8cae41a6a50e93a8965c0ce732298be&path=/src/NodaTime/Text/LocalDateTimePatternParser.cs).

Unfortunately this was after the 1.0 release, so you'll either need to grab the current code, or wait for 1.1 to be released (hopefully soon).

We *don't* currently accept it when parsing just a `LocalTime`. If you want that, please log a feature request - we'd probably look at it for 1.2 (which will have a lot of text features), although I'm not sure what the representation would look like. (`LocalTime` itself doesn't support the idea of "end-of-day midnight".)